# Spring MVC objects storage in application

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a Spring MVC application.
For example I have a simple JSP page that displays list of Contact objects.
User can add, remove objects. The question is about the way of Contact objects storage. I cannot (by some reasons) use database. How can I anyway store list of objects globally for application?

Comment: Does this have to be persistent? Serialize your list as XML or JSON (or other) and write it to a file.

Comment: it must be stored across whole application lifec-cycle. After I restart server it the list should not be lost.

Comment: Then write your own database file with XML or JSON.

Comment: Can you give me link to some tutorial, please?

Comment: Just google JSON or XML serialization in java.

Answer (score 0):

According to this

> it must be stored across whole application lifec-cycle. After I
>   restart server it the list should not be lost

you can use H2 or HSQLDB database and keep it content into single file, located in configurable path. Anyway, to keep some persisted data, you should use local file or remote storage, so, i think, it would simplify solution if you use such kind of database.